# Counting the amount of 2 characters in a string without pointers

Tags: c

I have to count the amount of times "e" and "E" occur in a string using a function, everything is working except for the counting of the e's

I believe my professor is looking for me to use strcmp but I cannot figure out how to use that correctly so I went a different route and that is not working either.

- sorry added main code

  ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define ARRLEN 30
    #define CODELEN 5

    //functions
    int numOfE(char [], int);

    int main(void)
    {
        //Variables
        char codeWord [CODELEN] ;
        char inputString [ARRLEN] ;
        int length = 0 ;
        int numbOfEs = 0 ;

        //Name
        printf("Grace Rombach\n") ;

        //Get codeword
        printf("Please enter the code: ") ;
        gets(codeWord) ;
        while (strcmp(codeWord, " ") !=0)
        {
            printf("Please enter the code: ") ;
            gets(codeWord) ;
        }
        //Collect string
        printf("Please enter a string less than 30 characters: ") ;
        gets(inputString) ;
        length = strlen(inputString);
        while (length >= 30)
        {
            printf("Please enter a string less than 30 characters: ") ;
            gets(inputString) ;
            length = strlen(inputString);
        }
        numbOfEs = numOfE(inputString,length) ;
        printf("%s -%d",inputString,numbOfEs) ;
  ```

  }

  ```
    int numOfE (char inputString[], int length)

    {
        int eCounter = 0 ;
        int i = 0 ;
        char charE = "E" ;
        char chare = "e" ;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if(inputString[i]== charE || inputString[i]== chare)
            {
                eCounter++ ;
            }
        }
        return (eCounter);
    }
  ```

Comment: please add the main to the code too, also explain 'not working'

Comment: `char charE = "E"` with the double quotes is a string, you want `char charE = 'E';` and `'e'`.

Comment: `strcmp()` is not the best tool for the job, just saying.

Comment: Turn on **and mind** your compiler warnings.

Comment: also you dont need to pass the length , `strlen` will tell you the length

Comment: also a stylistic best practice, please don't add spaces before line-terminating semicolons, never ever have I seen that.

Comment: Also you don't need to pass or determine the length, the first `'\0'` tells you to stop :)

Comment: `char codeWord[5]` is very tight, also checking the input length *after* the overflow is no good. I suggest beginning with `#define ARRLEN 100` and `#define CODELEN 100`.

Comment: Comparing the length to the maximum _a posteriori_ is not going to help, hence why `gets` was removed from the standard. You want to establish a maximum _a priori_ with `fgets` or use GNU `getline` where the memory is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Should be (using more normal coding conventions too)

```
  int numOfE (char *inputString)
  {
      int eCounter = 0;
      char charE = 'E';
      char chare = 'e'
      for (int i = 0; i < strlen(inputString); i++)
      {
          if(inputString[i] == charE || inputString[i] == chare)
          {
              eCounter++;
          }
      }
      return eCounter;
  }
```

the reason it failed was because yo used "E" instead of 'e'

Although I would do

```
          if(inputString[i] == 'E' || inputString[i] == 'e')
```

and leave out charE and chare since it makes the intent clearer

Comment: the "e" was definitely my problem thank you, however we have not learned pointers yet which is what I believe the *inputString is and we were asked to pass the length to the function. But overall you fixed my problem, thank you

Comment: @GraceRombach `*inputString` and `inputString[]` mean exactly the same thing, the former is considered stylistically the norm. BTW, very nice clean code. One style change, declare the variables when you use them not at the start of the function  ie `int numOfE = numOfE(....);`

Answer (score 0):

As @pm100 mentioned the problem was that you need to use single quotes for characters instead of double quotes.

Here's a full example where I use a rather general version of the character counter function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // to use the "tolower()" function
#include <string.h> // to use the "strlen()" function

int countChar(char inputString[], char c)     
{
  int counter = 0; 
  int length = strlen(inputString);
  int i = 0;       
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (tolower(inputString[i]) == tolower(c)) counter++;   
  }                                                    
  return counter; 
}                 
 
int main () {
        char str[] = "hamEde";
        char c = 'e';
        printf("The (case insensitive) count of '%c's in \"%s\" = %d\n", c, str, countChar(str, c));
}
```

Output: `The (case insensitive) count of 'e's in "hamEde" = 2`